# cant replace more than 1 underscore with a single underscore in the string(regex python)

Tags: regex, python-3.x, replace

```
def strip_string(s):
    import re
    replaced_string = re.sub('[^\\w/]+', '_', s)
    return replaced_string
print(strip_string('h^&ell`.,  |o w/p]{+p__orld'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `regex` to replace more than one `_` in the string with a single `_` you can do

`replaced_string = re.sub('[_]+', '_', s)`

Full code,

```
import re

def strip_string(s):

    replaced_string = re.sub('[_]+', '_', s)
    return replaced_string
print(strip_string('h^&ell`.,  |o w/p]{+p__orld'))
print(strip_string('hello___world__'))

# Output
h^&ell`.,  |o w/p]{+p_orld
hello_world_
```